# integer print wrong number

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//odd number generator with int k as the max number
void genap_generator(){
    int k;
    printf("Masukkan batas bilangan genap = ");
    scanf("%i", &k);
    printf("Bilangan genap dari 0 sampai %i adalah :\n");
    for (int i=0; i<=k;i+=2){
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
    
}
int main(){
    genap_generator();
    system("pause");
}
```

I made a program to generate odd numbers with int k as the max number but when i print the integer it doesnt print k[print error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4nHZ.png)

Comment: `printf("%i\n", i);` -- The format specifier for a signed integer is `"%d"`.

Comment: How would the compiler know that you wish to print `k`? It can't read your mind. There's no `printf` statement containing `k` and so `k` doesn't get printed.

Comment: Change `printf("Bilangan genap dari 0 sampai %i adalah :\n");` to `printf("Bilangan genap dari 0 sampai %i adalah :\n", k);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the line where you want to print `k`: `printf("Bilangan genap dari 0 sampai %i adalah :\n");`, you didnt pass `k`.

The line should be: `printf("Bilangan genap dari 0 sampai %i adalah :\n", k);`.

What the function does print right now is what is placed on the stack where `k` should have been.

Also, you are printing all the even numbers, if you want to print the odd numbers start from `i=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to our community! Could you use English language in your code next time?

The problem was with printing in printf, you did not declare which variable you wanted to print. Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//odd number generator with int k as the max number
void genap_generator()
{
    int k;

    printf("Enter an even number limit = ");
    scanf("%i", &k);
    // Had to declare, which variable to print
    printf("The even numbers from 0 to %i are:\n", k);

    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i += 2)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }    
}

int main()
{
    genap_generator();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: thanks I cant believe i missed that one , it's an assignment for my uni homework so i wrote in bahasa but I'll try to change it to english next time